# Closure-compiler and strange pre code

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler

I often use online closure compiler (https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) to minify my JS code. Now I'm trying to integrate this process into PhpStorm via "External tools" and I'm having very strange result. Everything works fine, except one thing - some strange code is printed before mine if I use **Set** variables. For example:
**Original code**:

```
function a(text) { alert(text); }
$(document).ready(function(){
    let mySet = new Set();
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
       a("CLICKED");
       mySet.clear();
       for(let i=0;i<10;i++) mySet.add(i);
    });
});
```

**Minified via WEB-tool**:

```
function a(b){alert(b)}$(document).ready(function(){var b=new Set;$("#myButton").click(function(){a("CLICKED");b.clear();for(var c=0;10>c;c++)b.add(c)})});
```

**Minified via command line** (*java -jar compiler.jar --charset UTF-8 --js closureTest.js --js_output_file closureTest.min.js*): https://pastebin.com/QqGXc6H7

---

Without **Set** variable:

**Original**:

```
function a(text) { alert(text); }
$(document).ready(function(){
    let mySet = [];
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
       a("CLICKED");
       mySet.length = 0;
       for(let i=0;i<10;i++) mySet.push(i);
    });
});
```

**Minified via WEB-tool**:

```
function a(b){alert(b)}$(document).ready(function(){var b=[];$("#myButton").click(function(){a("CLICKED");for(var c=b.length=0;10>c;c++)b.push(c)})});
```

**Minified via command line**:

```
function a(b){alert(b)}$(document).ready(function(){var b=[];$("#myButton").click(function(){a("CLICKED");for(var c=b.length=0;10>c;c++)b.push(c)})});
```

---

As you can see, WEB-tool compilation works fine, but what's wrong with command line compiling?

Comment: Good question. Is it javascript versioning? Or is there a char-set issue?

Comment: @wahwahwah: I didn't understand you, what do you mean?

Comment: So, I could be wrong, but [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is different from `var set[]` and it might be how the compiler is treating your variable declaration.

Comment: @wahwahwah: yes, you are right, Set() is different from [] (array). but why does Closure WEB-tool compile it perfectly in contrast to the command line compiler?

Comment: It looks like your local compiler believes your environment is missing Set, and is automatically polyfilling it for you. Basically, it's providing its own implementation of Set so that it doesn't have to rely on a native one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found solution (thanks **[shiftweave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9922902/shiftweave)**).
It needed argument `--rewrite_polyfills false` to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler by default "transpiles" code from the latest supported language version to EcmaScript 5.  To support this it also include the necessary polyfills.  If you don't need the polyfills, `--rewrite_polyfills false` as stated in another answer is one solution but a better one may be to set the `--language_out=ECMASCRIPT_2015` or `--language_out=ECMASCRIPT_2017` if you are only targetting browsers that support these later language features.

You should set your intended `--language_out` regardless as the default may change in the future.